# HTML5 on older browsers?

Tags: html, validation

I'm working on a page and I'd like to use HTML 5's `setCustomValidity`.  It's easy enough to test if the browser supports it:

```
var inpt = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]; // etc.
if(typeof(inpt.setCustomValidity) != 'function')
  // workaround here
```

But I'm not sure if there's any reasonable way to deal with this.  Sure, I can write a setCustomValidity function in that case, but it won't have the context (right?) to deal with the event.  Unless maybe I have functions call it with their own names?

If there's a library that handles this (Modernizr etc.) that would be great.  If there's a good workaround I'd be happy to use that.

I have some ugly hacks in mind but I'd prefer to do this the *right* way if possible, whatever that might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for if you don't mind using jQuery: 
http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/index.html

Fallback for form validation in browsers that don't support them:
http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/demos/webforms.html

Comment: Those look great.  Do you happen to know if they work with `pattern=""`?

Comment: pattern is in the supported attribute list, so I guess so; No experience with it though

Comment: The second link is broken

Comment: I loved [formality](http://lingerbird.com/projects/open-source/formality/documentation-v1.0.0.php), it best suits for my needs, hope that would help someone too.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard great things about Modernizr and based on the attention its received I would definitely say give it a try.

Comment: Does it handle `setCustomValidity()`?

Comment: I can't find anything in the documentation regarding it but it would seem that it would be an easy enough implementation to include. I would say download it and try it out. If it does not work, then I don't think it would be too difficult to write your own setCustomValidity extension method.

Simply have a global 2D array that has an object's selector paired with its message. The extension method can push both into the array upon being called. Upon validation if a given texbox doesn't validate correctly then use the array as reference and set the focus / display message.